# break file txt in java

Tags: java, loops, io, break

my data in notepad
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...` why when `str ==5` using break does not good work, my data is supposed stop when in numbers 5 ...just display `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...`

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Numbers.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNextInt()){
                int str = sc.nextInt();
                for (int i=0; i<str; i++){
                    if (str == 5);
                    break;
                }

                System.out.print(str+ " ");
            }       
            sc.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: for what this for loop?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: how should be do you suggest?

Comment: you don't need this for loop .just use if(str == 5)

Comment: Your loop isn't actually doing anything...

Comment: It's just taking time but not actually processing any code or changing your output at all...

Comment: i want to display 1,2...5 not all numbers 1 to 10 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change your code to be easier and do:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Numbers.txt"));
            int str = sc.nextInt();
            while (sc.hasNextInt() && str != 6){
                System.out.print(str+ " ");
                str = sc.nextInt();
            }       
            sc.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i want to display 1,2,3,4,5 not 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: @rickyhitman10 Then look at my code it will give you 1 2 3 4 5 or use this code but change `str != 5` to `str! = 6`.

Comment: Sorry @rickyhitman10. Thanks for pointing out my error. I updated my answer to fit your needs

Comment: This code takes care of your break for you. Unless you were planning on doing extra logic where str == 5 ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get rid of the ; after `if(str==5);`  There should be no ;.

```
for (int i=0; i<str; i++){
    if (str == 5)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The thing is your loop isn't actually doing any processing.  You are looping a max of 6 times but you aren't doing anything in your loop.  You aren't changing your output at all the loop is completely useless in this case...

You are just breaking out of the for loop not the while loop.  If you want to break out of the while loop you should do like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Numbers.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNextInt()){
                int str = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print(str+ " ");
                if (str == 5)
                {
                   break;
                }
            }       
            sc.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using braces to avoid problems like this.

Comment: can you give me example due i'm still beginner

Comment: You need to break out of the while loop. As has been mentioned, the for loop is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Just to respond with the example, the `;` after your if ends that if statement. Use braces `{}`

```
if(str==5){
    break;
}
```

so:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Numbers.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNextInt()){
            int str = sc.nextInt();
                if (str == 5){
                    break;
                }

            System.out.print(str+ " ");
        }       
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

An alternative way to do it would be to load the entire line, split on `,` and then iterate through the following array and print out if there is a 5 and break if you find it

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to loop as long as the number has not been found.

```
boolean foundFive = false;
Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Numbers.txt"));
while (sc.hasNextInt() && !foundFive) {
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print(number+ " ");
    if (number == 5) {
        foundFive = true;
    }
}       
sc.close();
```

Comment: i guess you could do foundFive = (number == 5;). But that's just my OCD talking.